# Angular: Reset index value in the same template

Tags: html, angular, html-table

I have a template of 3 tables having same JSON as parent like this.

```
<tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let row of reportingData.RecommendationData; let i=index">
        <tr *ngIf="row.swRecommendations">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td> {{row.swRecommendations.deviceID}}</td>
        </tr>
     </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Another table body

```
<tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let row of reportingData.RecommendationData; let j=index">
        <tr *ngIf="row.licenseRecommendations">
            <td>{{j+1}}</td>
            <td> {{row.licenseRecommendations.deviceID}}</td>
        </tr>
     </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

All these tables are in the same template. I'm assigning index values to different variables(i & j) but increment is happening i.e. if first table is having 5 rows, second table is starting with 6 not 1. How to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you could just split `reportingData.RecommendationData` into two arrays?

Comment: Or you could have a funciton that calculates the index like: `<td>{{getIndex(row)}}</td>` In the function you could have logic that determines if it should have the reset index value. You place the function in the component

Comment: It's not possible , If you are running the code which you asked in you'r question then it should start each index from 0.

Answer (score 1):

I tested you'r code and indexes are starting from 0 . 
Please review my code.

**Component.html**

```
<h1>First Table</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <ng-container>
        <tr *ngFor="let a of array;let i = index">
            <th>{{i + 1}}</th>
            <th>{{a.name}}</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</table>
<h1>Second Table</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <ng-container>
        <tr *ngFor="let a of array;let j = index">
            <th>{{j + 1}}</th>
            <th>{{a.name}}</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styles: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {}
    public array = [
        { id: 1, name: 'aaa'},
        { id: 2, name: 'bbb'},
        { id: 3, name: 'ccc'},
        { id: 4, name: 'ddd'},
        { id: 5, name: 'eee'},
        { id: 6, name: 'fff'},
    ]
}
```

Comment: Strange, but in my code its taking first table's last index in the second table

Answer (score 0):

H recently faced the same issue, since we are indexing it and increment it will be like that, the solution of this problem is like this Filter your data in the ts

```
    this.a= this.reportingData.filter(x => x.swRecommendations);
    this.b= this.reportingData.filter(x => x.licenseRecommendations);
    <tr *ngFor="let row of a"> <tr *ngFor="let row of b">,
```

and then remove the if condition and iterate the data in HTML like this let row of reportingData   , editing needed based on your consition in ts